# Context-free grammar for language with unequal numbers of a and b

Tags: formal-languages, context-free, automata

I've been trying to get a CFG for the language of all words with unequal numbers of a and b, i.e.

$$\{u \in \{a, b\}^* \mid \text{number of occurrences of $a$ and $b$ in $u$ are unequal} \},$$

but it seems that I keep getting specific cases instead of the general case.

Here are some that I have tried:

(S being the start Variable)

```
S -> A | a | b
A -> aV | bT
V -> aV | bL
L -> aV
T -> bT | aM
M -> aT
```

This one's problem is that you can't create 2 of the same string if it's the lesser amount of alphabet.

So I've tried

```
S-> A | B
A -> aV | a
V -> aV | aVb | bVa
B -> bT | b
T -> bT | aTb | bTa
```

This one also has problem because if you have a you need to have b on the opposite end.

Additionally, I know this is one of the huge problem in my process is that you start with 'a' or 'b' and use that as a flag for if there is more 'a' or there is more 'b'...

I've been trying to think the way where you can input an alphabet (i.e `S -> aV | bV`) so that I can start with any variable and I use cases or condition to go to different variable, but I end up with infinite variable situation.

Answer (score 9):

Here are some hints:

1. Break the language into two parts: $L_a = \{ w : \#_a(w) > \#_b(w) \}$ and $L_b = \{ w : \#_a(w) < \#_b(w) \}$. Below we concentrate on $L_a$.
2. Figure out a grammar for the language $L_= = \{ w : \#_a(w) = \#_b(w) \}$. Here the idea is that $L_= = (aL_=b + bL_=a)^*$.
3. Use the identity $L_a = L_=(aL_=)^+$ to construct a grammar for $L_a$.

Comment: So basically I need to figure out the CFG of `(a+b)*` where # of a = b, then I use concatenation to put them all together?

Comment: Well, here is a CFG for $(a+b)^*$: $S \to aS|bS|\epsilon$. Unfortunately, your exercise is more complicated. (Unless by $a,b$ you meant arbitrary expressions $\alpha,\beta$ rather than the symbols $a,b$.)

Comment: Would this be correct? `(a+b)∗ | # of a = b: S→aSb|bSa|abS|baS|e` (edited)

Comment: Here is a word it doesn't cover: aabbba. Don't guess, try to prove that your solution works.

Comment: Do you have an e-mail dat I can send you my possible solution? I did the work on mathtype and I don't know how to write it on this post

Comment: Unfortunately I am not able answer personal questions. If I remember correctly, MathType can export LaTeX, which you can use here (it is used in my answer). You can answer your question yourself with you suggested solution.

Comment: Then just answer me if this is correct. For having the same number of a's and b's in a string here is the CFG: $S→aSb|bSa|aAa|bBb|\epsilon$; $A→aAb|bAa|bSb$; $B→aBb|bBa|aSa$; if this is correct, I think I have the correct solution

Comment: Hmmm I think it's wrong because if I input a double alphabet (e.g. aAa) I must return the opposite double alphabet (e.g. bBb). Basically I can't have aaaa.... :( How is this this possible~~~~~~~

Comment: it must be $S→aSb|bSa|abS|baS|Sab|Sba|\epsilon$ !

Comment: @LarsChung, I suggest you stop guessing and start trying to *prove* that your grammar works. Your last effort doesn't accept $aabbbbaa$.

Comment: I don't know how to $prove$ if my answers work, I can only test cases. Anyway, I've improved it as $S→aSb|bSa|abS|baS|Sab|Sba|SS|ϵ$. Even if I type google how to prove if CFG works, it doesn't give me anything

Answer (score 5):

The unequal number of $a$'s and $b$'s have
{equal number of $a$'s and $b$'s} with {{extra $a$'s } or {extra $b$'s}}

Extra $a$'s or extra $b$'s can be

- at the beginning
- at the end
- in between (ANY WHERE) and any number of times

Let $P$ derive strings with extra $a$'s

Let $Q$ derive strings with extra $b$'s

Let $X$ derive equal number of $a$'s and $b$'s

Let $A$ derive only $a$'s

Let $B$ derive only $b$'s

And $S$ derives the final language

\begin{align}
&S\rightarrow P\mid Q\\
&P\rightarrow XAX\mid PP\\
&Q\rightarrow XBX\mid QQ\\
&X\rightarrow aXb\mid bXa\mid XX\mid \varepsilon\\
&A\rightarrow aA\mid a\\
&B\rightarrow bB\mid b
\end{align}

Answer (score 4):

Remember that the following approach is also feasible:

1. Come up with a pushdown-automaton for the language.
2. Use the standard construction to get a grammar.

That's not a very insightful process (in terms of learning how to construct grammars) but it works.

Comment: Yea, I know how to build a PDA with this language, but I have no idea how to convert it to CFG...

Comment: @LarsChung Check the proof that PDA and CFG are equally powerful; it usually gives constructions in both directions.

Answer (score -5):

I know this is like a very old post, (and way past your homework deadlines), but here's the solution:

$\qquad\begin{align*}
  L &\to L_a \mid L_b \\
  L_a &\to L_=aL_a \mid L_=aL_= \\
  L_b &\to L_=bL_b \mid L_=bL_= \\
  L_= &\to aL_=bL_= \mid bL_=aL_= \mid \varepsilon 
\end{align*}$

Comment: How did you get there? Why is it correct? How can the OP or any other reader learn from this for the next task?

Answer (score -5):

$$
\begin{align*}
&S → U \mid V \\
&U → TaU \mid TaT \\
&V → TbV \mid TbT \\
&T → aTbT \mid bTaT \mid \epsilon
\end{align*}
$$

I hope it will predict a context-free grammar for the language consisting of all strings over $\{a,b\}$ containing an unequal number of a's and b's!

Comment: This is identical to [Vigneshwaran's answer](http://cs.stackexchange.com/a/28834/9550) from nearly a month ago, except that you use different non-terminals. And your answer is bad for exactly the same reasons theirs is: no explanation at all of why you think it is correct.

Answer (score -6):

$$
\begin{align*}
&S\to aB \mid bA \\
&A\to b \mid bS \mid aBB \mid \epsilon \\
&B\to a \mid aS \mid bAA \mid \epsilon
\end{align*}
$$

Comment: Where did you get that from?  Why is that grammar correct?  What are the ideas behind it?   We're not looking for one-line answers with no explanation; we're looking for answers that come with explanation, justification, etc.

Comment: FYI - this is wrong, "ab" is a match.